# Removing old logo filepath from layout view in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, jpg, file-path

I'm using a very old MXD in ArcMap. We have a wall map set up with symbology to show one type of our strucutres. The problem is that in our legend, our old company logo file path has replaced the image of our logo. I can't find a way to remove it.

[image: Old Logo in Legend]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the select tool to select the image place holder and simply press delete key to remove it from your layout

[image: Select element control]

Comment: I've tried selecting on the center of where the logo was, and clicking delete. ArcMap sends me a warning that if I delete, it will delete the whole data frame.

Comment: Has the originator applied a grouping to the layout elements or is it something to do with the display order?

Comment: I'm not sure. I found a solution though. I saved a different image to that exact file path in our drive. When I reopened ArcMap, the new image was in the logos old spot. Then I deleted that image.

Comment: Sounds like a solution!